# what's the meaning/function for '??' in php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I found out that laravel use '??' symbol in php

the example code is

```
  $this->connections->connection($config['connection'] ?? null)
```

What does '??' mean ?

Comment: It's the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), introduced in PHP 7. Not related to Laravel in any way.

Comment: Thank you @axiac